# Connect session undefined when loading new page

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I'm a bit new to sessions and now when I'm trying to use them the session is always undefined for me when coming to the next page after a successful login as an example.

If my login is successful I do the following:

```
var session = req.session;
session.user_id = String(item._id);
session.user_secure = security.security(session.user_id);
```

Then I redirect to another page:

```
res.writeHead(302, {
    'Location': '/backstageArea'
});
res.end();
```

And then I try to find the session again doing this:

```
var session = req.session;

console.log("uid: " + String(session.user_id));
console.log("hid: " + session.user_secure);
```

which results in the session being undefined.

These are my last three things in my app.configure:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret', store: store, key: 'sid', cookie:{secure:true}}));
app.use(app.router);
```

Could it be since I'm redirecting to a new page that I lose the session?
Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: I not sure, but you may place `app.get` and `app.post` above `app.use(app.router)`?

Comment: Are you using https? And what type of store are you using?

Comment: @robertklep I'm using var store = new express.session.MemoryStore; and no https.

Comment: @damphat nope it doesn't work.

Comment: @just_user no https?, so remove `secure: true`

Comment: @damphat, thanks, that solved it. Would you like to put it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `cookie:{secure:true}`, you tell your express application and browsers to send that cookie over **https only**.

So if you don't use `https`, you can remove `secure: true`

---

Secured cookies are useful feature to protect your sensitive cookies from mand-in-the-middle attack, They are much more useful when you use both `http` and `https` on the same domain.

If you want to use https on via `nginx` or `apache`, you may need:

```
app.set('trust proxy', true); // if remove this line, express will refuse to send https cookie to nginx or apache
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var session = req.session;
session.user_id = String(item._id);
session.user_secure = security.security(session.user_id);
```

edit to

```
req.session.user_id = String(item._id);
req.session.user_secure = security.security(session.user_id);
```