# Expressjs Debugging Secure Session

Tags: session, express, https, passport.js

I have recently updated my session options to include `secure: true` as my web hosted version of my application is using `https`. Unfortunately, this addition is messing with my passportjs login authentication, which I feel is related to this change in the setting, but I'm not sure how I can accurately debug this scenario or what I should look for in my developer tools. Here is my session setup. I have `true` set in my env config.

```
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: process.env.REDIS_ENDPOINT || 'localhost',
        port: 6379
    }), 
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'local-ss',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.HTTPS_SET || false,
        domain: process.env.DOMAIN_NAME || 'localhost'
    }
}));
```

Comment: Can you define _"messing with my passportjs login authentication"_?

Comment: When I trigger the login request it accepts the post, but returns my back to the login page. I am unable to access any part of the site that requires authentication

Comment: Sounds like cookies don't get set at all. In the dev tools, look in the "Network" tab (at least in Chrome) and check if the server's response after the login call is setting a session cookie.

Comment: @robertklep you are right, I checked my cookies and there is not one named `cookie.sid` appearing which should store this information. I get a server response of `302 Found` on the POST with the right login information. Are you aware of how this session option might be getting rejected by passport.js?

Comment: Do you have a reverse proxy in front of your Express app that is handling the HTTPS part, or do you create an HTTPS server from Node yourself?

Comment: My Nginx server config has a portion that is handling the HTTPS. I did not make any adjustments in Expressjs to work with https

Comment: Right, in that case, you need to configure Express to trust proxies (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20858319/893780) and also [the documentation of `express-session`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#secure)).

Comment: @robertklep that was exactly the answer I was looking for and the biggest issue with my session setup. Thank you so much for your help. That solved my problem